# JAXB: Updating XML file after using ArrayList .add() method

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

I have a simple Java application in which it will asks the user to insert Customer Details, and these are then save to an ArrayList.  I want to store this ArrayList into an XML File using JAXB XML parser.  At a certain point in my code, I'm getting input from the user and save that input using the ArrayList .add() method.

After foloowing some tutorials, and implementing JAXB code, it turned out that only one record is being saved, and overwritten once new data is inserted.

I have 3 classes so far in my Application:

CustomerRecord.java - This is the class where I'm inserting the XML annotations

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;
@XmlRootElement
@XmlType(propOrder = { "name", "surname"})  
public class CustomerRecord {

private String name;
private String surname;
private String cellular;


public String getName(){
    return name;
}

public String getSurname(){
    return surname;
}
@XmlAttribute
public String getCellular(){
    return cellular;
}

public void setName(String name){
    this.name = name;
}

public void setSurname(String surname){
    this.surname = surname;
}

public void setCellular(String cellular){
    this.cellular = cellular;
}
```

App.java - This is the class where I'm saving the xml file.

```
public void addCustomer(){
    CustomerRecord r = new CustomerRecord();
    r.insertCustomerDetails();
    crecords.add(r);
    try{
JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(CustomerRecord.class);  
Marshaller jaxbMarshaller = jaxbContext.createMarshaller();
jaxbMarshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, Boolean.TRUE);
File XMLfile = new File("e:\\storage.xml"); 
jaxbMarshaller.marshal(r, XMLfile);
    } catch (JAXBException e){
    //TODO Catch block
    e.printStackTrace();  
    }
}
```

Now the result I'm getting is this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="true"?>
 -<customerRecord cellular="356 99606060">
  <name>John</name>
  <surname>Doe</surname>
</customerRecord>
```

If new data is inserted, the above xml file would be overwritten rather than having a new record beneath it, and I'm ending up always with one element of the arraylist saved in the xml file.

What I really want is to have multiple records beneath each other, but I'm not achieving this!

Please help!

Comment: You are trying to produce a non-[well-formed](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML#Well-formedness_and_error-handling) xml file (single root element rule). On [http://howtodoinjava.com/2013/07/30/jaxb-exmaple-marshalling-and-unmarshalling-list-or-set-of-objects/](http://howtodoinjava.com/2013/07/30/jaxb-exmaple-marshalling-and-unmarshalling-list-or-set-of-objects/) you find a example for marshalling and unmarshalling a list of Objects.

Comment: Hi fabian. A good tutorial but it really doesn't answer my question. The example is used for training purposes and it doesn't fit my question.  I want to store data while in a 'for loop' asking data from the user.  And re data, that's enough for me.  I dont wont any elaborate data stored in the xml file.

Answer (score 0):

I hope you would have figured out the issue now.

jaxbMarshaller.marshal(**r**, XMLfile); --- r is always one element.

jaxbMarshaller.marshal(**crecords**, XMLfile); -- crecords is the arraylist you want.

Does this answer?